# Show if $|z+w| = |z|+|w|$ then there exist $\lambda \geq 0$ such that $z = \lambda w$

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

Show if $|z+w| = |z|+|w|$ then there exist $\lambda \geq 0$ such that $z = \lambda w$.

I'm in my first complex variables course, cant use polar coordinates (haven't seen them) so how would you approach this?

Comment: Hint, Write $z=a+bi$, $w=c+di$ and calculate those absolute values.

Comment: "complex variable *curse*"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Haha, math is indeed a curse to a students.

Comment: Geometry: In a plane triangle, if the triangle inequality is equality, what does that mean geometrically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, if $z=a+bi$ then $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$ So you can use this and just work through the algebra:

Let $z=a+bi$ and $w=c+di.$ Now assume $|z+w|=|z|+|w|,$ then

$$\sqrt{(a+c)^2 + (b+d)^2}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+d^2}$$
square both sides:
$${(a+c)^2 + (b+d)^2} = {a^2+b^2}+{c^2+d^2}+2\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}$$
continue to expand
$$\underbrace{a^2+c^2+b^2+d^2}+2ac+2bd=\underbrace{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}+2\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}$$
and cancel where one can:
$$ac+bd=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}$$
square both sides again:
$$(ac)^2+(bd)^2+2abcd=(ac)^2+(bc)^2+(ad)^2+(bd)^2$$
and finally
$$2abcd=(bc)^2+(ad)^2 $$
and you should be able to draw the necessary conclusion from here.